# I want my program to terminates when the 5x trials are over

Tags: python

*This is my code, everything seems to work fine, only part of the trial is not working.*

```
counter = 1

max_attempt = 5
secrect_nu = 313
num = int(input("Guess my number: "))
while num != secrect_nu:
    max_attempt = max_attempt - 1
    print(emoji.emojize(":winking_face_with_tongue: :winking_face_with_tongue: \U0001F606"))
    num = int(input(f"HHHHH! You stuck in my loop you've {max_attempt} left \nGuess my number: "))
    if num >= max_attempt:
        print("Game Over!")
        break
    counter += 1

# while num >= max_attempt:
#
#     break

if num == secrect_nu:
    print("==========================================")
    print("Congrats, You've broken the chain of my loop.  ")
    print("You got my secrect number in your " + str(counter) + "th attempt.")
```

**I want to solve the trial issue, I want the program to stop if the user exceeds 5 trials**

Comment: Why are you comparing num to max_attempt? Shouldn't you compare counter?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this should work for you:

```
counter = 1
max_attempt = 5
secrect_nu = 313
num = int(input("Guess my number: "))
while num != secrect_nu:
    max_attempt = max_attempt - 1
    num = int(input(f"HHHHH! You stuck in my loop you've {max_attempt} left \nGuess my number: "))
    if counter==4:
        print("Game Over!")
        break
    counter += 1

if num == secrect_nu:
    print("==========================================")
    print("Congrats, You've broken the chain of my loop.  ")
    print("You got my secrect number in your " + str(counter) + "th attempt.")
```

It is going to check everytime if `counter` is 4 or not and `num` is equal to `secrect_nu` or not.

Comment: If this solves your problem, don't forget to mark this as answer.